# HttpClient Header has Request-Id in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Good day,
I am currently using ASP.NET Core to make request to some service endpoints with strict Header rules.
I discovered that RequestId is added automatically to my request header, i need to remove this.
Here is my code snippet;

```
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(mainUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authorization);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
            var responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(mainUrl, model);
            var errorMessage = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
            resps = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I also tried using flur but the situation remains thesame. Below is the snippet of the code;

```
            var resps = await url.AppendPathSegment("/merchant/api/paymentinit")
               .WithHeader("Authorization", authorization)
               .PostJsonAsync(model)
               .ReceiveString();
```

I have also tried following suggestion from [enter link description here](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/disable-application-insights-correlation-id-headers-on-httpclient-requests-in-aspnet-core/)
But nothing seems to work. Can someone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a `DelegatingHandler` and set `Activity.Current = null`

```
public class DisableActivityHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public DisableActivityHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
    {

    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Activity.Current = null;

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

To read more about this issue see David Fowlers comments here

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19044

Comment: I saw the post. But how does the handler works with the code i wrote above.

Comment: @MatthewOdedoyin Since your are using core, you can used a named client with `AddHttpClient` so you can add the handler. Then use IHttpClientFactory to get access to your client, you can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1